# How to fix android studio gradle errors from unexpected shutdown

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am developing android applications in android studio 2.1. My system was shut down unexpectedly due to the power failure.Then after power comes i restarted my system open the android studio all my API components are showing error but my gradle file showing that it was successfully build what was the problem here i am getting don't know This screen shot will explain you more
[image]

It was showing gradle successfully build but still error remains same can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean the project using the gradle task clean then invalidate the cache of android studio and restart (File/invalidate cache and restart). 
after that synchronise your project with grade and build it again. I think it would solve your issue.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, Close your IDE and Follow these two simple steps to solve this problem.

> Delete caches folder of the path
>
> `C:\Users\user\.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches.`

> Delete specific project's caches folder too
>
> `E:\AndroidProjects\SampleApp\.idea\caches`